# drop event dataTransfer is undefined when simulate a drop event from content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, drag-and-drop, content-script, custom-events

I am making a chrome extension with a content script injected into a host page. 
There is a drag-drop area in the host page, I made a customEvent using dispatchEvent()  to simulate the drop event.
The event triggered as expected, but dataTransfer I defined cannot be seen by the host page script.

Host page: seems to be using jQuery.
Content script: pure JavaScript.

-host script:

```
 this.dropArea.on("drop", function(e) {
        someMethod(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files)
    });
```

-my content script:

```
var dropArea=document.querySelector("#dropArea");
dropArea.addEventListener("drop",function(e){
    console.log(e);//console can output e without problem.
});
var evtDrop=new CustomEvent("drop");
evtDrop.dataTransfer={files:["e:\\test\\test.jpg"]};
//evtDrop.initCustomEvent("drop",true,true,null); //with or without this, the same.
dropArea.dispatchEvent(evtDrop);
    });
```

The goal is to put some files in the dropArea and let the host page process it with someMethod().
But I was given an error:
**"Cannot read property 'files' of undefined"**

I can't figure out why this isn't work, please give me your advice.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Local files cannot be supplanted in this fashion, otherwise it'd be a super huge security hole.

Comment: Thank you  wOxxOm, that makes sense. So I can trigger "drop" event but can't pass data through it? I am still curious how to simulate a drop event grammatically instead of drag & drop it by mouse, any idea?